# SQLite recursive CTE UPDATE working in 3.18.0, SQL_CONSTRAINT in 3.19.0

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

We have a SQLite CTE UPDATE that was working in versions up to and including 3.18.0, but began failing in 3.19.0 with a FOREIGN KEY constraint (error 19).

The following is a sample toy database that shows the behavior.

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28 18:48:43 424a0d380332858ee55bdebc4af3789f74e70a2b3ba1cf29d84b9b4bcf3e2e37
sqlite> .dump t2
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE T2 (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , ParentId INTEGER NOT NULL , Name TEXT NOT NULL , FavoriteState INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES T2(Id) );
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,0,'/',2);
CREATE INDEX idx_pid_t2 ON T2 (ParentId);
CREATE INDEX idx_files_favstate_t2 on T2 (FavoriteState);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_pnc_t2 ON T2 (ParentId, Name);
COMMIT;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE under_favorite_path(parent) AS ( VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT T2.Id FROM T2 JOIN under_favorite_path ON T2.ParentId = under_favorite_path.parent ) UPDATE T2 SET FavoriteState = 1
WHERE Id IN under_favorite_path;
sqlite> select * from t2;
1|0|/|1
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE under_favorite_path(parent) AS ( VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT T2.Id FROM T2 JOIN under_favorite_path ON T2.ParentId = under_favorite_path.parent ) UPDATE T2 SET FavoriteState = 2
WHERE Id IN under_favorite_path;
sqlite> select * from t2;
1|0|/|2
```

Disabling foreign keys in 3.19.0 allows the UPDATE to succeed.

```
sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.19.0 2017-05-22 13:58:13 28a94eb282822cad1d1420f2dad6bf65e4b8b9062eda4a0b9ee8270b2c608e40
sqlite> .dump t2
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE T2 (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , ParentId INTEGER NOT NULL , Name TEXT NOT NULL , FavoriteState INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES T2(Id) );
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,0,'/',2);
CREATE INDEX idx_pid_t2 ON T2 (ParentId);
CREATE INDEX idx_files_favstate_t2 on T2 (FavoriteState);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_pnc_t2 ON T2 (ParentId, Name);
COMMIT;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE under_favorite_path(parent) AS ( VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT T2.Id FROM T2 JOIN under_favorite_path ON T2.ParentId = under_favorite_path.parent ) UPDATE T2 SET FavoriteState = 1
WHERE Id IN under_favorite_path;
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE under_favorite_path(parent) AS ( VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT T2.Id FROM T2 JOIN under_favorite_path ON T2.ParentId = under_favorite_path.parent ) UPDATE T2 SET FavoriteState = 1
WHERE Id IN under_favorite_path;
sqlite> select * from t2;
1|0|/|1
```

Is this an issue with our CTE that should've been flagged previously or is this something that might've regressed in later SQLite versions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the CTE, but that the table contains invalid data (`0` is not a valid ID):

```
sqlite> pragma foreign_key_check;
table       rowid       parent      fkid
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
T2          1           T2          0
```

When the row gets modified in any way, the constraint is checked:

```
sqlite> update t2 set name = name;
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Apparently, the old version did not check the constraint when the FK column was not modified.

Comment: Yes, definitely looks like the behavior now. Am wondering if this change was intentional or not based on this line from the  3.19.0 release notes https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_19_0.html because I read to be opposite of what is happening: _Avoid unnecessary foreign key processing in UPDATE statements that do not touch the columns that are constrained by the foreign keys._

Comment: That "unnecessary foreign key processing" actually [is "updating unaffected indexes"](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/477bea9ed0dd0fa6). There appears to have been some other change …